# Compiling with OpenSSL ssl_conn errors

Tags: c, linux, openssl, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a small .c file which uses OpenSSL includes, at first I had problems compiling but I solved it installing libssl-dev and that solved the include errors.

But now when I try to compile I get:

```
‘ssl_conn’ has no member named ‘encrypted’
‘ssl_conn’ has no member named ‘write_seq’
‘ssl_conn’ has no member named ‘read_seq’
```

The code for the lines of the error is:

```
ssl_conn* sslCon;
sslCon->encrypted = 0;
sslCon->write_seq = 0;
sslCon->read_seq = 0;
```

A friend told me it could be because the .c file was coded for an old version of OpenSSL, but I am not sure. Does someone knows what could be causing this and how to solve it?

Comment: My suggestion would be to check the ssl_conn type in the header files to see if it really has those members that are erroring out.

Comment: No it doesn't have them, but where are they then? Do you know if an old version of OpenSSL does have them? or maybe i am missing some libs.

Answer (score 0):

ssl_conn is not part of the OpenSSL API and never was. I only found reference to it in some sample code exploiting OpenSSL, and it was defining it itself. Assuming you aren't trying to use that exploit code, my guess is there's an example floating around online from which you got the code you are trying to compile. So check your definition of ssl_conn and ensure it has the fields that are missing.